# fatal error in C - no such file or directory

Tags: c, cs50

I am working through the CS50 course and downloaded the cs50.h file into the same directory as my cs50.c file.

However, I am receiving a fatal error `cs50.h: No such file or directory` when i include the cs50.h header in my program

```
#include <cs50.h>
```

Any suggestions, please? I'm using Code::Blocks 20.03

Cheers

Comment: Welcome. Have you tried `#include "cs50.h"`

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that. Irritatingly, I keep getting the same error message. I have no idea why though as the header file is in the same directory as the .c file...

Comment: Do you have the file `cs50.h` in your computer?

Comment: yep, in the same folder as the cs50.c file!

Answer (score 1):

- if it's not from an official lib you can't use <> you need to use "". But it's not a fatal error it doesn't really matter.
- if it's in another directory you need to specify the path like so `include "/file/anotherFile/cs50.h"`.
- if it's your current directory you can write it like that it might fix the problem `"./cs50.h"`

hope it helped you !

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that. Irritatingly, I keep getting the same error message. I have no idea why though as the header file is in the same directory as the .c file...

Comment: what's your compiler

Comment: I'm using Code::Blocks

Comment: if you can try the gcc compiler it's more reliable

Comment: @john_joseph Code::Blocks is not a compiler, it's an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your file in the cs50 workspace. You would've set up a repository upon beginning the course.

Answer (score 0):

for this I changed my compiler to clang and included cs50 as `#include "cs50.h"` instead of `#include <cs50.h>` and it worked fine. need to include all c files in the task, eg in vs code, tasks.json file should look like:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\clang.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\*.c",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\main.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\mingw64\\bin\\clang.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```